# SIFT feature detection in C

Tags: opencv, feature-detection, sift

I am working on a SIFT feature detection in Opencv. The problem is the libraries supporting this project (ex: features2d,nonfree) are available only in .hpp and I need to write in C. So any suggestions?

I'm hoping that I don't have to translate the libraries.

Comment: http://answers.opencv.org/question/58178/can-i-use-sift-in-c/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.hpp usually indicates a C++ header. If you really need a C interface, write a wrapper library. But I would just use a C++ compiler for the whole project.